# Laravel Websockets - Why do we still need valid Pusher API keys

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-websockets, laravel-broadcast

I am using [Laravel WebSockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets) on my project.

And it is told that Laravel WebSockets is pusher replacement.

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=
PUSHER_APP_HOST=
```

But my question is
Why do we still need valid pusher API keys?
It worked only when I put valid pusher API keys.

And can't I get done it without pusher API keys?

Can anyone help me with better knowledge?

Thank you

Comment: Laravel websocket was designed to use pusher configurations to allow users to switch without any hassle. Meaning if you had been using pusher services up until now, you could easily switch to laravel websocket and you would only need to update environment variables to restart business as usual.

Comment: I hadn't been using pusher services up yet. I am developing new project. And it seems it requires valid pusher API keys though.

Comment: Just checked their doc: If you never used pusher service, check this: From the documentation: `::: tip When using Laravel WebSockets as a Pusher replacement without having used Pusher before, it does not matter what you set as your PUSHER_ variables. Just make sure they are unique for each project.`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tsjfer
Tried to do with my PUSHER_variables, but getting error.

Comment: OK Nevermind, IT works great! Thank you!